# How to display 2 div's inside a div inline with each other?

Tags: css

HTML code:

```html
<div class="quarter dropdown-check-list" id="kpi_type_quarter">
  <div id="list2" class="block" tabindex="1">
    <label class="form-label">Select Quarter</label>
    <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list2')">Select Quarter</span>
    <ul id="list2_items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="1" id="Q1"><label for="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="2" id="Q2"><label for="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="3" id="Q3"><label for="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="4" id="Q4"><label for="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="list6" class="block" tabindex="100">
      <label class="form-label">Select Year</label>
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list6')">Select Year</span>
      <ul id="list6_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021">2021-2022 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are these 2 `<div>`'s inside a `<div>` wrapper, but both of them are displayed one below the other on the site. How do I get them to display in a line horizontally? Thank you.

Comment: As per your code, you don't have 2 divs in a div.

Comment: There is inside `kpi-type-quarter` there is `list2` and `list 6`.

Comment: You don't have </div> after </ul>, Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, you don't have 2 divs in a div. You need to move `</div>` tag after `</ul>` and set display as flex to the wrapper div container.

```html
<div class="quarter dropdown-check-list" style="display: flex;" id="kpi_type_quarter">
  <div id="list2" class="block" tabindex="1">
    <label class="form-label">Select Quarter</label>
    <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list2')">Select Quarter</span>
    <ul id="list2_items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="1" id="Q1"><label for="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="2" id="Q2"><label for="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="3" id="Q3"><label for="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="4" id="Q4"><label for="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- move div here -->
    <div id="list6" class="block" tabindex="100">
      <label class="form-label">Select Year</label>
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list6')">Select Year</span>
      <ul id="list6_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021">2021-2022 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### For that you can use the `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row;`

```css
#kpi_type_quarter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="quarter dropdown-check-list" id="kpi_type_quarter">
  <div id="list2" class="block" tabindex="1">
    <label class="form-label">Select Quarter</label>
    <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list2')">Select Quarter</span>
    <ul id="list2_items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="1" id="Q1"><label for="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="2" id="Q2"><label for="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="3" id="Q3"><label for="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="4" id="Q4"><label for="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="list6" class="block" tabindex="100">
    <label class="form-label">Select Year</label>
    <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list6')">Select Year</span>
    <ul id="list6_items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021">2021-2022 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! but it isnt working rather it shifted more to left.